# Is this script (to iterate over files, pass them as arguments to another script, count failures and sum successful outputs) correctly written?

Tags: bash, exitstatus

I am working on an exam practice problem in which we need to invoke a script on a file. If the exit status is non-zero, we increment the number of fails by one, else we increment the sum variable by one.
Since we don't actually have this script, I just wanted to verify that what I wrote on paper is correct, assuming that the script we are calling is called compute, and args are all the file arguments.

```
SUM=0
NUMFAILS=0
SCRIPT=./$compute

for args in *; do
    num=$SCRIPT args
    if (($? -ne 0)); then
        NUMFAILS++
    else
        SUM=(($SUM+$num))
    fi
done
```

Comment: The title should reflect your actual question itself, not the thing the question is about.

Comment: ...btw, in general, the right way to solve this is to write a `compute` script yourself that behaves in a way that's a reasonable facsimile of what you need and test with that. Questions about a script that don't isolate and focus around a specific problem with that script tend to be frowned on here, when not explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum=0
numfails=0

shopt -s nullglob

for args in *; do
    if num=$(./compute "$args"); then
       ((sum+=num))
    else
       ((numfails++)) 
    fi
done
```

- You can use `$?` for testing exit status of the last command or you can test it with `if` directly: `if command; then echo CMD OK; fi`
- You can assign output of a command to a variable while testing its exit code: 
  `if output=$(command); then echo CMD OK; fi`
- Do **not** use uppercase variables as they could collide with environment and internal shell variables
- It is not wise to store commands in variables: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
- `NUMFAILS++`: you still need to use `((` to evaluate the expression: `((numfails++))`
- `num=$SCRIPT args`: you need to use command substitution to substitute the output of a command: `num=$(./script "$args")`
- `args` is a variable, you need to expand it with a dollar sign: `"$args"`. Quotes are necessary to prevent word-splitting. Note that in arithmetic context, for example `((++numfails))`, you don't need to use dollar sign
- You might want to use `shopt -s nullglob` to skip the `for` loop if there are no files in your directory
- On @CharlesDuffy's suggestion, If you are using `set -e`, you should use preincrement `((++numfails))` and `((sum+=num)) || true` to handle cases where `set -e` would terminate the script when the result of either arithmetic expression is equal to 0
- Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Might make it a preincrement instead -- `(( ++numfails ))` -- just so we don't fail with `set -e` on the first run. Not that folks should be using `set -e` anyhow. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point, thanks! Unfortunately, if first `num` is a 0, it will also fail with `set -e`.

Comment: Heh -- that's a good point. Might need to make it `((sum+=num)) ||:` to handle that case.